# python and HTML form options.I want to run a function with parameters from html form and get the results

Tags: python, html, function, post, parameters

I have an HTML form with a drop-down list and some radio buttons. The user selects the options and then i run a function to get some results.

In the POST method I use self.request.get(parameter) and successfully get what the user has selected from the drop-down list and the radio buttons. Then I want to run the function "solution" and print out the results. Here is my code:

```
def post(self): 
   global results
   results=""
   problem = self.request.get('prob')
   time = self.request.get('q')
   cost = self.request.get('r')
   experience = self.request.get('exp')
   level = self.request.get('lev')
   results=solution(problem,time,cost,experience,level)
   self.response.out.write(results)
```

but it just prints out "None" do I miss something?? (the function solution is correct and returns a string,I checked it separately)

Comment: What's `self.request` contain? ie, are `prob`, `q`, `r`, `exp` or `lev` missing, resulting in `None` default value from `.get()` ?

Comment: might help to add the framework you are using as well (i.e. where does self.request get defined?)

Comment: prob,q,r,exp,lev are the names of the drop-down list and radio buttons. I chose some of them and printed them in order to check if the values pass successfully and it worked

Comment: the code above the post:class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
 def get(self):
       self.response.out.write(form)

Comment: If the code isn't too long, I'd suggest adding your `solution` function as well.

Comment: the "solution" function is a bit long. but I checked it separately in python codeskulptor and returns the results. I could post a part of it

Comment: @user1826791 And just to double-check, it actually returns a value, correct? It doesn't just create the string and end?

Comment: the function "solution" returns a string such as "Action 1",valueofaction1, "Action2", valueof action2 etc.

Comment: this is the return statement:  return "Action1",valueofaction1,"Action2",valueofaction2